# Backbone router using jQuery $.get() promise to determine logged in state of user not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use a jQuery promise to make `authenticated.done` wait until the `$.get()` in `.isAuthenticated` returns, but I'm not getting the result I was expecting... the function inside `authenticated.done` runs before the preceding `$.get()` returns and thus does not work. Am I doing something wrong or am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

```
isAuthenticated : function() {
    // make a request to the server and see if the response is a login form or not
    // this should just return true or false, not actually handle login etc
    var authenticated = false;
    console.log("authenticating...");

    var ready = Promise.from(null);

    $.get("/loggedin")
    .then(function(data, textStatus) {
        var rtnVal = false;
        if (textStatus == "success" && !(data instanceof Object)) {
            console.log("failure returned");
        } else {
            console.log("success returned");
            rtnVal = true;
        }
        return rtnVal;
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        authenticated = result;
    });

    return ready.then(function () {
        return authenticated;
    })
},

render: function (view) {

    if(this.currentView) this.currentView.destroy();

    var authenticated = this.isAuthenticated();

    authenticated.done(function (response) {
        if (response == true) {
            console.log("Authentication success!");
            // set the currentView
            this.currentView = view;

            // render the new view
            this.currentView.render();

            // set the view's menu items
            if (this.currentView.navLink !== undefined) {
                $(this.currentView.navLink).addClass("active");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Authentication failed...");
            view = new app.LoginView();
            view.render();
            this.currentView = view;
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

And the console output:

```
authenticating... router.js:45
Authentication failed... router.js:89
success returned router.js:55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what your code should look like using jQuery's Deferred/Promise objects:

```
{
    authenticate: function () {
        var authentication = $.Deferred();

        $.get("/loggedin")
        .then(function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus === "success" && !(data instanceof Object)) {
                authentication.resolve(data, textStatus);
            } else {
                authentication.reject(data, textStatus);
            }
        });
        return authentication.promise();
    },
    render: function (view) {
        if (this.currentView) this.currentView.destroy();

        this.authenticate()
        .done(function (data, textStatus) {
            this.currentView = view;
            this.currentView.render();
            $(this.currentView.navLink).addClass("active");
        })
        .fail(function (data, textStatus) {
            view = new app.LoginView();
            view.render();
            this.currentView = view;
        });
        return this;
    }
};
```

Notes:

- since `then` is called regardless of success or failure of the GET request you don't need a `fail` callback.
- I've renamed the function to the more appropriate `authenticate`, because it is an action, not a state
- jQuery does not care if you pass `undefined` to it, so your `if (this.currentView.navLink !== undefined)` check is superfluous
- You might want to use `data` and `textStatus` in the authentication callbacks somehow. If you don't need them, call `resolve()` or `reject()` without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is `Promise` object that you are using, but using standard jquery deferred object the code will look:

```
isAuthenticated : function() {
    // make a request to the server and see if the response is a login form or not
    // this should just return true or false, not actually handle login etc
    var authenticated = $.Deferred();
    console.log("authenticating...");

    $.get("/loggedin")
    .then(function(data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success" && !(data instanceof Object)) {
            console.log("failure returned");
            authenticated.reject();
        } else {
            console.log("success returned");
            authenticated.resolve();
        }
    }, function () {
        authenticated.reject();
    });

    return authenticated;
},

render: function (view) {

    if(this.currentView) this.currentView.destroy();

    var authenticated = this.isAuthenticated();

    authenticated.done(function (response) {
        if (response == true) {
            console.log("Authentication success!");
            // set the currentView
            this.currentView = view;

            // render the new view
            this.currentView.render();

            // set the view's menu items
            if (this.currentView.navLink !== undefined) {
                $(this.currentView.navLink).addClass("active");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Authentication failed...");
            view = new app.LoginView();
            view.render();
            this.currentView = view;
        }
    });

    authenticated.fail(function () {console.log('failed')});

    return this;
}
```